# PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric (throw exception instead)

Tags: php, php-7

I am using PHP 7.0 and want to throw exceptions when invalid arguments are provided to methods. Using this method as an example:

```
public function setType(int ...$type)
{
    if(count($type) == 0)
    {
        $this->type = null;
        return;
    }

    $this->type = $type;
}
```

When I call this method like so:

```
$test->setType(1,2,3,'11fffdghht');
```

I only get an Notice message back:

```
"PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in ...."
```

However, if I call it like so:

```
$test->setType(1,2,3,'asdasd');
```

I get an exception (which is what I acually want to achieve):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Network\Parser::setType() must be of the type integer, string given
```

How can I make this happen in the first case as well, and not only print out an Notice message as the arguments is not an integer?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try [strict typing](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Thanks for your reply. This would only work if the file where the method is called from uses strict typing, right?
So I can not make the class determine that whoever calls this class method must only provide integers?

Comment: Right, it's the calling file that's responsible for declaring strict types. Otherwise, it will be coerced and a Notice raised.